# Image uploadation editing and remove with react.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-router, nlp-question-answering

Hey my question has three 3 parts and it is about React.js. If i had a website and it has an admin panel in which i can control the whole `website` that is showing to all over the world.

- Is it possible that i can change images on the website through admin panel with react .js
- If it is possible then how to do it with react.js then can you refer me something.
- if it is not then what should i do to make it happen and change the images on the website.

Comment: If you have a website and have access to the code, you can do pretty much whatever you want. You can start by following a few React tutorials to get started. I recommend egghead.io

Comment: Thanks but people say that best way to do these things are with PHP but I alike Javascript more that why I am asking is that possible in react.js

Comment: You can learn either one. React is very popular. But learning with PHP will also help you learn the web programming lifecycle.